# form_for wrong number of arguments in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using form_for tag and Its working in Rails 3.0.4 environment.
But when I tried to update my project to Rails 4.It gives following errors

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2). Here is my code

```
   <%= form_for @email, :url => alerts_path do |f| %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: just try with  <%= form_for @email do |f| %>
   <% end %>

Comment: I have also tried this,i got the same error that i have mentioned above.

Comment: Show me the controller code..

Comment: I had @contact model and i had created virtual fields init as i didn't want to store the data, so at that time i got this kind of error, for me solution was creating fields insted of using virtual attribute.

Comment: Try methods in config/initializers/simple_form.rb. I changed the lambda in config.label_text and gave it 3 arguments instead of 2 and it fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any issue with your form_for, can you post backtrace of exception ? may be another gem is overriding default form_for ?

Comment: as the popular answer says, client_side_validations gem can also cause it

Answer (score 23):

Try to remove things that may try to change things in views.

In my case the problem was with **client_side_validations gem**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been documented and fixed on git: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/603
I just changed my Gemfile to point to github and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why yet, but removing the "meta_search" gem from my Gemfile fixed this exact problem for me on Rails 4.

If you google this problem you may find this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/535) that attributes it to the "client_side_validations" gem, but using the suggested "rails-4-quick-fixes" branch of that repo didn't fix the issue for me.

I think that the error with `simple_form_for` was a red herring, as I was getting the same error even using Rails built in `form_for`, and was getting `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)` regardless of how many arguments I actually passed into either method.

meta_search hasn't had a new release since February 2, 2012, so I can only assume something in the gem wasn't behaving nicely with Rails 4. If I discover what the problem was specifically, I'll update this answer. It seems kind of lame to have to "just stop using" meta_search, but that's as much as I can offer so far. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks bud, that fixed mine

Comment: uh oh :-/ We use ActiveAdmin and meta_search is a dependency. So we can't upgrade to Rails 4 if we want to keep AA??

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct.
Try changing it like this:

```
<%= form_for(@email, url: alerts_path) do |f| %>
  #form fields goes here
<% end %>
```

I tried to see if there is any change in source-code for `form_for` in Rails 4.0 API; It's still the same.

Have a look at Line 262 at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for your help but i have tried this solution, It gives me the same wrong number of arguments error.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood: Try adding `method: :post` along with `url` and check.

Comment: Are your `alerts` resources or not? In `routes.rb` ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove gem 'meta_search' from your gem file, and look into using gem ransack instead. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack