# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_for @video, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :translation_handwritten %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone have any idea on why this might be throwing such an error? I'm pretty lost...
[image: Here is the screenshot of my error]

Here is the Gemfile for my app. Are any of these possible culprits? What would I need to change?
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'carrierwave' #see README: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'whenever'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
```

**UPDATE**
When I change @video to any other model I have, it doesn't error. (it obviously won't work correctly because I need this to be attached to a video). What could be causing this?

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course, :qa_complete, :qa_id, :subject, :title, 
  :translate_complete, :translator_id, :type_complete, :typer_id, :video_id, :due_date, :translation_handwritten

  validates :video_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #add uniqueness in db too

  mount_uploader :translation_handwritten, TranslationsUploader


end
```

**UPDATE 2** Here is my application trace:

```
app/views/shared/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__form_html_erb___611020419_98374470'
app/views/videos/translate_video_handwritten.html.haml:54:in `_app_views_videos_translate_video_handwritten_html_haml__702424599_100568110'
```

Comment: You likely have a gem/library that's overriding the default behavior of `form_for`. Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278247/form-for-wrong-number-of-arguments-in-rails-4     common culprits are meta_search and client_side_validations

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` automatically gives you multipart true. Try getting rid of that.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Answer (score 0):

Check with following modification:

```
<%= form_for( @video, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is video a resource? Also, do you have routes for videos? 
If yes, try commenting the carrierwave code in your model.
If that doesn't work can you paste the full application trace?

Comment: No, I just have users as a resource and the routes associated with them sometimes include videos. In my app, videos get assigned to users. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `url` as parameter. Like [that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification).

I hope helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<% form_for "video", :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```