# no implicit conversion of Sass::Importers::Filesystem into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, compass-sass, sass-rails

I am updating my `Ruby on Rails` application from `4.0.1` to rails version: `5.2.3` and ruby version `2.6.5`.
After installing bundle, server is running properly. However, When I open page in browser, I am getting following error:

#### no implicit conversion of Sass::Importers::Filesystem into String

My `Gemfile` & `Gemfile.lock` are attached bellow.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829886/in-require-no-such-file-to-load-iconv-loaderror
gem 'iconv' # version 1.0.4 was installed by `bundle` so I fixed it to avoid future problems

gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate_mongoid'

# controllers and views
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid'

# wickedWizard
gem 'wicked'#, '1.3.0'

# https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/195
# Coffee Scripts were not compiling somehow without downgrading to "1.4.0"-- Phew- A long awaited issue.
gem 'execjs'
gem "therubyracer", :platforms => :ruby
#gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
gem 'compass-blueprint' # http://compass-style.org/blog/2012/05/20/removing-blueprint/
gem 'backbone-rails'
gem 'fancy-buttons', require: false
gem 'eco'
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wicked_pdf', "1.1.0" # Downgrade & lock wicked_pdf gem to 1.1.0 until v2 release (https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/827#issuecomment-500563629)
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'activeadmin'

# todo: to look alternate of meta_search if it's used in application
# removed meta_search to fix form_for issue with object:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278247/form-for-wrong-number-of-arguments-in-rails-4/25664460#25664460
#gem "meta_search" 

gem "formtastic"

# auth
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'cancan'

# services / support
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1' # in favour of gem "aws-s3"
gem 'papercavalier-ruby-aaws', require: 'amazon/aws', git: 'git://github.com/xlymian/ruby-aaws.git', ref: '40af30'
gem 'exception_notification', "2.5.2", require: 'exception_notifier'
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm', "~> 3.15.2"
end

gem 'oink'

gem "memcachier"
gem 'dalli'

# Preview Email
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development

# gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
gem 'utf8-cleaner'

gem "activerecord-import"

gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer', group: [:production]
# gem 'simple_xlsx_writer', '~> 0.5.3'
gem 'xlsx_writer', '~> 0.4.4'
gem 'write_xlsx'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'roo'

gem 'active_admin_editor', github: 'ejholmes/active_admin_editor'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: [:production]

gem 'route_downcaser'
gem "http"

gem "recaptcha", '~> 0.4.0'

gem "figaro" # allows to add environment variables, use config/application.yml to load env vars.
# moved vendor/plugins to gems
gem 'dynamic_form'#, '~> 1.0'
gem 'prefinery'#, '~> 0.2.1'

# deprecation gems
# gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'oauth'
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/xlymian/ruby-aaws.git
  revision: 40af30c991e5c6962b8541b24022139f373c80b1
  ref: 40af30
  specs:
    papercavalier-ruby-aaws (0.8.1)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git
  revision: be1f7516a8e781bedc6bd3cc34d5395c7c72b3f3
  specs:
    compass-rails (3.1.0)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (< 5.1)
      sprockets (< 4.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor.git
  revision: 86f964be3071cd938c3cd17ad00df94ece3a50c0
  specs:
    active_admin_editor (1.1.0)
      activeadmin (>= 0.4.0)
      ejs
      rails (>= 3.0.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (2.4.0)
      arbre (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.1)
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n (~> 0.4)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
      kaminari (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      ransack (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1)
      sprockets (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      sprockets-es6 (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.2)
    activejob (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
    activemodel-serializers-xml (1.0.2)
      activemodel (> 5.x)
      activesupport (> 5.x)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activerecord-import (1.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
    activeresource (5.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0, < 7)
      activemodel-serializers-xml (~> 1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0, < 7)
    activestorage (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arbre (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    aws-eventstream (1.0.3)
    aws-partitions (1.239.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.77.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.239.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.25.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.71.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.54.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.77.0)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.1.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
    backbone-rails (1.2.3)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bson (4.6.0)
    bson_ext (1.5.1)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    carrierwave (2.0.2)
      activemodel (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      addressable (~> 2.6)
      image_processing (~> 1.1)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
    chunky_png (1.3.11)
    ckeditor (5.0.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-blueprint (1.0.0)
      compass
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    dalli (2.7.10)
    delayed_job (4.1.8)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.1)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.1)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dynamic_form (1.1.4)
    eco (1.0.0)
      coffee-script
      eco-source
      execjs
    eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1)
    ejs (1.1.1)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (2.5.2)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
    excon (0.68.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    fancy-buttons (1.2.0)
      compass (>= 0.11)
    fast_xs (0.8.0)
    ffi (1.11.2)
    ffi-compiler (1.0.1)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
      rake
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    fog-aws (3.5.2)
      fog-core (~> 2.1)
      fog-json (~> 1.1)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (2.1.2)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.58)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.3)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    formtastic (3.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    haml (5.1.2)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 5.1)
    has_scope (0.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1)
    hashie (3.6.0)
    hodel_3000_compliant_logger (0.1.1)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    http (4.2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0)
      http-form_data (~> 2.0)
      http-parser (~> 1.2.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    http-form_data (2.1.1)
    http-parser (1.2.1)
      ffi-compiler (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
    httparty (0.17.1)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    iconv (1.0.8)
    image_processing (1.9.3)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
    inherited_resources (1.11.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      responders (>= 2, < 4)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    kaminari-mongoid (1.0.1)
      kaminari-core (~> 1.0)
      mongoid
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.7.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.19)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.3.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    memcachier (0.0.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mime-types (3.3)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2019.1009)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_magick (4.9.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    mongo (2.11.0)
      bson (>= 4.6.0, < 5.0.0)
    mongoid (7.0.5)
      activemodel (>= 5.1, < 6.1)
      mongo (>= 2.5.1, < 3.0.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    murmurhash3 (0.1.6)
    newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    oauth (0.5.4)
    oink (0.10.1)
      activerecord
      hodel_3000_compliant_logger
    omniauth (1.9.0)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pdfkit (0.8.4.1)
    pg (1.1.4)
    polyamorous (2.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
    prefinery (0.2.1)
      activeresource (>= 3.1)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (3.12.1)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-ssl-enforcer (0.2.9)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.3)
      actioncable (= 5.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      activestorage (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    ransack (2.3.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (= 2.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    recaptcha (0.4.0)
    ref (2.0.0)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    roo (1.13.2)
      nokogiri
      rubyzip
      spreadsheet (> 0.6.4)
    route_downcaser (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
    ruby-ole (1.2.12.2)
    ruby-vips (2.0.16)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    ruby_parser (3.14.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sass (3.4.25)
    sass-rails (5.0.8)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    sexp_processor (4.13.0)
    spreadsheet (1.2.5)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)
      babel-source (>= 5.8.11)
      babel-transpiler
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    temple (0.8.2)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.6)
    unix_utils (0.0.15)
    utf8-cleaner (0.2.5)
      activesupport
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    wicked (1.3.4)
      railties (>= 3.0.7)
    wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
    will_paginate (3.2.1)
    will_paginate_mongoid (2.0.1)
      mongoid
      will_paginate (~> 3.0)
    wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.5)
    write_xlsx (0.85.7)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
      zip-zip
    xlsx_writer (0.4.4)
      activesupport
      fast_xs
      murmurhash3 (>= 0.1.4)
      unix_utils
    zip-zip (0.3)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_admin_editor!
  activeadmin
  activerecord-import
  aws-sdk-s3 (~> 1)
  backbone-rails
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bson
  bson_ext
  byebug
  cancan
  carrierwave
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  compass-blueprint
  compass-rails!
  dalli
  delayed_job
  delayed_job_active_record
  devise
  dynamic_form
  eco
  exception_notification (= 2.5.2)
  execjs
  fancy-buttons
  figaro
  fog-aws
  formtastic
  haml-rails
  htmlentities
  http
  httparty
  iconv
  inherited_resources
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  kaminari
  kaminari-mongoid
  letter_opener
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  memcachier
  mini_magick (~> 4.8)
  mongo
  mongoid
  newrelic_rpm (~> 3.15.2)
  oauth
  oink
  omniauth
  papercavalier-ruby-aaws!
  pdfkit
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  prefinery
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rack-ssl-enforcer
  rails (~> 5.2.3)
  rails_12factor
  recaptcha (~> 0.4.0)
  roo
  route_downcaser
  rubyzip
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  therubyracer
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  utf8-cleaner
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  wicked
  wicked_pdf (= 1.1.0)
  will_paginate
  will_paginate_mongoid
  wkhtmltopdf-binary
  write_xlsx
  xlsx_writer (~> 0.4.4)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing the [`compass-rails`](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails) gem (which is EOL) solved this issue for me.

Comment: Worked for me but unfortunately I'm on a legacy project depending on it

Comment: Thank you! This caused me some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with specifing a version of `saas-rails` to specific one - in your case I think you need to define it as `'sass-rails', '~> 6.0.0.'` in Gemfile.

Answer (score -1):

Then trying to overwrite sass-rails with sassc-rails and it`ll work

Comment: I have added it too. Still, the same issue exists

Answer (score -1):

Were you ever able to figure this out? Just came across this as well and this is the only result that comes up in a search.